# how to lift geometrically integralness using etale(+something else) morphisms

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Take $X$ and $Y$ to be $k$-varieties, where $k$ is a field of characteristic 0.
Assume also that $X$ is geometrically integral, and let $f: Y \to X$ be an etale a morphism of $k$-varieties.

*Question:* by the addition of which conditions on $f$ do we have that $X$ geometrically integral implies that $Y$ is geometrically integral?

*Some thoughts*: when I think of etale I think of local properties, and geometrically connectedness is not. Also geometrically connectedness is not preserved by base change (if I recall correctly). So I doubt that etalness alone can allow us to lift geometrically integralness (even though I can't think of a counterexample, but I'm sure there are easy ones). Maybe $f$ finite (and etale) will suffice?

Comment: What is your definition of variety? If it's just "reduced and of finite type", then $X \amalg X \to X$ is a counterexample.

Comment: What if we take in the definition of variety "integral" as well?

Comment: $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C} \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{R}$ is finite étale, $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{R}$ is geometrically integral as an $\mathbb{R}$-scheme, but $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}$ is not geometrically integral as an $\mathbb{R}$-scheme.

Comment: Thanks for these counterexamples. Do you know if there is any property we can add to $f$ in order for $Y$ to be geometrically irreducible whenever $X$ is?

Comment: I think it's unlikely, but I am not an expert.